# Compile errors don't show up when using XCTest with swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest

it doesn't seem like anyone has had this issue before but I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and started adding some UI Test Cases with swift. When I use swift there are no compile errors or warnings that show up. So when I do something wrong it just says "Build Failed" but doesn't say why. Nothing shows up anywhere.

Yet when I make the tests in objective C it works just fine with the compile errors and warnings and NSLocalizedString works too...

Does anyone know how to make Xcode show the compile errors and warnings on tests that use swift?

Comment: I have seen something like that when I moved complex nested code to swift 2.0. This expression prevented any error message by the compiler. Make sure to look into the log: there is probably more detailed information.

Comment: It may be that the compiler is crashing. as @GerdCastan says, check the build log for further details. Then, if the compiler *is* crashing raise a bug with Apple.

Comment: I wasn't getting anything put out to the logs. The only things it would show were the warning for the actual project. It seems the answer from ferunandu was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. What fixed the problem on my side was to make sure that my **Schema** included "*Analize*" or "*Test*" for the **UI Test Target**. Like so:

[image]

[image]

---

Only then warnings and errors messages started popping up in my UI test classes:

[image]

[image]